# Fprintf functions in c programs that arent redirected with stdout

Tags: c, printf, pipe

I've created a C program in `Unix` where fprintf is declared like this:

```
       #Include<stdio.h>
        ...
       fprintf(stdout,"Example\n");
```

The problem is when I try to redirect `stdout` to another file like this:

```
      $./ExampleProgram > file.txt
```

The expected result is to have is `Example` inside the file, but instead the output is like this one (I type on command promt lines 00 and 02 below):

```
     00. BASH4.1$./ExampleProgram > file.txt 
     01. Example
     02. BASH4.1$cat file.txt
     03. BASH4.1$
```

If I redirect the stderr the output is like this one:

```
     00.BASH4.1$./ExampleProgram &> file.txt
     01.BASH4.1$ cat file.txt
     02.BASH4.1$
```

There's no output at all

Any idea why this is happening?

EDIT: The problem *may* be the Buffer of the fprintf but I've tried to fix it using `fflush(stdout)` but it doesn't work

EDIT2: Added more details.

Comment: When you execute the program, without trying to redirect `stdout`, does it output to your console?

Comment: Doing `fprintf(stdout, ...)` is no different from doing `printf(...)`, so there's something other wrong. Are you sure you don't print to `stderr`?

Comment: Is there really a `$` on line 01? The most likely explanation is that your `fprintf` prints to `stderr`, not to `stdout`. If so, this is why you should *always* copy-and-paste code samples; re-typing them can make it impossible to see what the real problem is.

Comment: yes, when I execute the program without redirecting `stdout` it prints the output to the console.

Comment: Have you tried redirecting both stdout & stderr `$./ExampleProgram &> file.txt` It appears you have something in your environment that is redirecting `stdout > stderr`

Comment: What does `echo example > file.txt` do? What shell do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested the example you've listed above. It worked just fine.
Here's the code for the example test c-file:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   fprintf(stdout,"Example\n");
   return 0;

}
```

---

compile with : gcc example.c -o example

I used bash environment to compile and run.

Maybe you forgot to include stdio.h ?